# Payment methods in admin panel not showing Paypal methods list in 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I click on "`Payment Methods`" tab .i.e. `System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods (from left tab under sales)`, It load the page as seen in the image and shows loading status forever.

[image]

I did notice one more thing, that only on this page, footer also don't show up. I tried by disabling all extensions from `app/etc/modules` folder but no luck.

I turn ON the path hints for admin and compared files with the my local running magento but these were identical.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having any other problems in the admin panel? I had some problems displaying contents on certain pages due to the memory limit for php being set too low. You may want to try increasing it in your php.ini.

You may want to set developer mode to true in .htaccess and uncomment the php debugging line in index.php to get more info on your problem.

htaccess add the following:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

index.php uncomment the following (line 77?):

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**EDIT:**Without permission to change .htaccess, refer to the line above at around 74 that says

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

You can add this just below the uncommented line to activate developer mode regardless of the environment variable being set.

If your memory is too low you'll probably see an error message indicating that situation when you go back to the page.

If your server config supports it, you can adjust the memory limit in the htaccess file. I use these values personally.

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I do not have access over htaccess and php.ini files as it is shared hosting. But can it be some other issue like adminhtml template file altered or something like that?

Comment: That's difficult to say without knowing if you edited anything there, or if the feature was working earlier.

Try this instead of editing htaccess. In index.php:
Add below the uncommented line for error display
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

It's the same as just above the line you're uncommenting, just without the surrounding section of code. I edited my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I have uncommented the line you mentioned in index.php at root directory, but still it is not giving any error. Rather displays half of the title of paypal block this time.

Comment: Set up a php info file and look at your memory_limit. If it's lower than 128MB it could be your problem.

Ideally Magento should not be set up on shared hosting, and I don't want to tell you not to run it there, but not having any access to htaccess or other things is a less than ideal setup, and you might run into more issues later on. Let us know about your memory limit and maybe we can figure something else out. I suppose it's possible that since you don't have access to these things that the ini_set command may not be working properly to allow you to debug php errors.

Comment: I get the memory limit by ini_get('memory_limit') function and it is 64M.

Comment: 64M for Magento will not do.512M is what is generally recommended.

Comment: I have a really good feeling that's going to be your problem, sorry. Either way, I have a feeling you will run into problems later on with your memory limit being set so low. You probably want to start looking into better hosting while you figure out if you can increase that limit. Either way it's hard to diagnose without being able to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

As half the page content is displayed to trouble shoot do the following:
1) check what all admin permissions given if all is ok here then.

Magento logs few things for developers( Your log should be set to on)
1. Go to var/log folder and check if there is any exception log or system log generated.
2. Also in var/reports folder check it any report there.

If in Magento log nothing is found then check site level error log.

If this too is ok then you need to check things at code level or check for .xml file in app/etc/  folder path

Answer (score 1):

After digging every which way to rectify this issue, I did find at least a work-around. I stripped the app/core/Paypal/etc/system.xml of everything inside the  tag.

Is it recommended? No. Will it get you out of your jam if you don't need PayPal? Yes.

As far as the issue itself, memory limit is at 512, timeout is over 1,000. Still get the error (or lack there of). Page loads just timeout at seemingly random amounts of the page. Only seems to happen on this page. Can't explain it, but have run out of time to debug it.